# Helm Configmap Template: Cannot add quotes to values in template

Tags: templates, kubernetes-helm, double-quotes, configmap

Here is my file in configfiles folder config.tmpl:

```
<Resource name="database"
  auth="Adam"
  type="java.sql.datasource"
  url={{ .Values.config.url }}
  password={{ .Values.config.pwd }}
  maxidle="10"/>
```

my config map template:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-config
data:
  {{tpl (.Files.Glob "configfiles/*").AsConfig | nindent 2 }}
```

here is my values.yaml

```
config:
  url: "jdbc db url"
  pwd: "xxxxxx"
```

when I render the template, here is the output

```
<Resource name="database"
  auth="Adam"
  type="java.sql.datasource"
  url=jdbc_db_url
  password=xxxxxx
  maxide="10"/>
```

Both url and password need to be in quotes, url = "jdbc_db_url" password="xxxxxx". 
I tried using the below approaches

```
1. url={{ .Values.config.url | quote}} this results in an error
2. url="{{ .Values.config.url }}" this works for password but not for url
```

Any ideas on how to get this correct?

Comment: What's the error, and what happens on the "doesn't work" case?  I'd expect both of the forms you show to include quotes as you expect.

Comment: Thanks David Maze for your reply. Here are the errors for both the approaches
1. Parse error at deployment.yaml: unclosed action
2. Parse error at deployment.yaml: unexpected unclosed action in command